# Solución al error "this repository is over its data quota. account responsible for lfs bandwidth should purchase more data packs to restore access."

Tags: c#

me ha salido el siguiente error clonando un repositorio de Github del cual soy colaborador: [image: Cómo puedo solucionarlo?]

He visto soluciones en las que me hacen aumentar mi cuota de Git LFS y no puedo pagar nada por el momento, hay alguna opción que me haga solucionar el problema para clonar el repositorio correctamente? Gracias.